# how to remove duplicated lables on a scatter plot

Tags: android

I want to add country codes to my scatter plot which contains variables over a period 8 years, but my plot has duplicated labels & the text plot command will therefore not display the country codes. How do I ensure that my x and y variables don't contain duplicated codes?

Thanks

Comment: It's always helpful to share some context, for example a code example of how you are storing/displaying the relevant data. the answer might depend on how exactly what you are trying to do, for example you could use a dictionary/list to store the values or you might need to sort and iterate your data.

Comment: My report seeks to analyze the association between violent conflict and refugee flows over an eight year period. I have data and country codes from both the country of origin as well as the destination country. I want to plot a scatter plot with labels that display the country codes. But because there are duplicates in the x & y variables the plot won't run. How do I remove the duplicated country codes?  1/2

Comment: I ran the following command:   plot(merged$year, merged$log.death,                                           xlab="years", ylab="conflict",                                              main="the occurrence of violence 2005 -2013",        cex.main=0.5,                                                              pch=NA, frame.plot=False).                                                          Text(merged$year, merged$log.death, labels= merged$dest.codes, cex=.05)      2/2

Comment: Edit your question and include the relevant information.